# Post request using tcp level

Tags: c#, winforms

I am able to login to a site (eaxmple.com) using webclient. but it is slower when site user is heavy. so i think to go with lower level.

I need suggestion is is good to go with tcpclient in c#. i need to manage cookie also after login. i tried to study this class from msdn but could not understand how to do post and get request using tcpclient.

i tried this for get request. but dont know about post and cookie management

```
 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            string header = "GET /?scope=images&nr=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                            "Host: www.bing.com\r\n" +
                            "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +
                            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n" +
                            "\r\n";

            var client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("www.bing.com", 80);

            // send request
            var stream = client.GetStream();
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

            streamWriter.Write(header);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            stream.Flush();

            // get response
            var response1 = streamReader.ReadLine();
```

Please suggest and provide me a link where i can start this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, to send a POST request, simply replace the verb 'GET' with 'POST' and there you go. To add actual payload (like form data) to the request, append a second line break at the end of your `header` variable and then the actual data in base64 format. Cookies are added as headers.
Just google for 'POST HTTP format' and look for example code, there must be dozens. An HTTP request is just a sequence of characters -- at least, you can start with it.

However, 'going down one level' won't help you if you have bandwidth or server load issues. Also, it's not easy to build a fully functional HTTP client. Lots of work for nothing.

Comment: hi Dercsár, 
is there any way to fetch data fast when server is too busy ? i mean when server has lots of user hitting site.

Comment: I could be a millionaire if I had a positive answer for this question :)

Comment: ohh thanks.. but u said 'going down one level' won't help you. but i saw article saying tcp level is faster then httpwenrequest.

Comment: You can save a few milliseconds from the networking overhead IF you lear n A LOT about IP networks and sockets and http traffic AND build a very specific HTTP client for your needs. But your problem is in the server, so it has to be dealt with in the server, right?

Comment: in my case if i can save 10 or 20 ms it would be great.

Comment: I am no expert of networking and HTTP traffic, so you will have to use google. Good luck, friend!